# Converting a datetime field timestamp from mysql to php

Tags: php, mysql

I have read about how to do this and most come up with this solution. I just want to display the time format.

```
$starttime = "1899-12-30 06:52:47";
<?php echo date("h:i:s",strtotime($starttime)); ?>
```

For some reason this returns "16:00:00"

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For one, the year 1899 is before the Unix Epoch which makes your code's output unpredictable at best.

Comment: Its failing because 1899 is before the Unix Epoch, which means the strtotime() function is product random results.

Comment: Just STOP using time(), strtotime and date() function, and START using DateTime class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments your date is before the unix epoch. [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) allows you to work around that.

```
$dt = new DateTime("1899-12-30 06:52:47");
echo $dt->format("h:i:s");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$starttime = "1899-12-30 06:52:47";
echo date("h:i:s",strtotime($starttime));
```

This code works ok for me and displays "06:52:47".  It could possibly be because 1899 is before the Unix Epoch (00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970)

Comment: The range of values that a UNIX `time_t` value can express is between 1901-12-13 and 2035-01-18. The epoch is `0`, but positive and negative values are permitted.