# converting datetime in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have the following DateTime called 'StartTime' field in mysql with '1899-12-30 12:17:52'

I am trying to convert it to a time on the screen for the users with php using

```
date('h:i:s A',strtotime($row_get_student_times['StartTime']))
```

but for whatever reason it always returns 4:00 PM no matter what the time. Any clue why this is happening?

Comment: the year `1899` is to old for strtotime to convert, you need to use `DateTime` http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are trying to show a date before the uinx epoch (1970).
Try this:

```
$date = new DateTime($row_get_student_times['StartTime']);
echo $date->format("h:i:s A");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php):

```
$datetime = new DateTime($row_get_student_times['StartTime']);
echo $datetime->format('h:i:s A');
```

Comment: This has already been answered [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18665288/1438393) and I believe the question is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dateTimeString = '1899-12-30 12:17:52';
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateTimeString);
echo $dateTime->format('H:i:s A');
```